# Bootstrap styling working but not the same looking anymore

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, .net-5

[image: [![from bootstrap][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3iea.png]

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>`
This is from getBootstrap.com

[image]

`<a id="manage" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:2px;" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">@UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>`
This is from my web app.

Hi, I am not sure what is happening here, I am using Bootstrap styling and used the same `btn-info` but the output is different as showns above.

Strange thing is that this was working fine, the same color when I used this last time a week ago, then back on my project today to continue working on it, suddenly different.

Maybe I have done something without knowing, I thought, so I went back one revision then two, but the color of the button is still the same, slightly brighter.

Launched the app on bothe Chrome and Edge, no difference.

Has anyone had such experience before?

====================
(Update1 09 Jul 2021)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/lib/datatables/DataTables-1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />

    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/DataTables-1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/DataTables-1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
```

I am using downloaded version of Bootstrap and above is the script code.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="margin:3px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#row_op" onclick="c => this.Collapsed = !this.Collapsed">
            Detail Expand/Collapse
        </button>

        <div id="row_op" class="collapse">
            <div class="row">
```

I was doing some troubleshooting yesterday and I think that strange color is only an indication of something is not working properly. I am also using `data-target` and `collapse` but they are not working at the moment.

What I am really struggling to understand is that, I deleted the current version of the project file completely and downloaded a commit I made a month ago(that is 5 revision ago) then ran it, strange color was still there and `collapse` did not work either.
This to me seemed like an issue with browser but tyring this on both Chrome and Edge was the first thing I did.

====================
(Update2 09 Jul 2021)

I remembered that I had published copy on my laptop for server testing. So launched it on the laptop, everything was normal, color of the button, spacing, collape all functioning.
Then I copied entire folder to my desktop and launched it again, Bootstrap still not working properly. Check version of Chrome 91.0.4472.124 the same on both computers.
At least this confirms that the code is fine but the issue is even more troublesome because now I found that my app can behave differently on different computers for totally unknown reason.
But what else could affect behavior of the code on a browser, if it is not the code or the browser?

Comment: It might be possible that you have overridden the `background-color` of `btn` or `btn-info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `Visual Studio 2019 community`, I switched test launch option from `IIS express` to `my app`, everything is working fine again. So the combination of what I use for testing affects the result.
My conclusion is that the user environment needs to be controlled but I don't think there is anything that can be done differently during development.

Answer (score 0):

Second image of button (blue background with black text) is official bootstrap info button design. The issue here might be a third party extension distorting your view of bootstrap main page. Be sure to test it in - no extension incognito mode.