# Bootstrap5 Info button is blue with black text instead of blue with white text like their demo

Tags: css, button, sass, frontend, bootstrap-5

My full code -- [Random Quote Generator Project in Codepen](https://codepen.io/featherPiano/pen/ZERqBYK?editors=1010)

I used Bootstrap5 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css.

The button style `btn-info` is not styling correctly. I know that I can manually change it, but I just want to understand why it is happening.

On the Bootstrap Demo Button for button style `btn-info` is blue and white..

[Picture of info button default style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2c7e.png)

However, when I added it to my code, the style is appearing this way:

[In my project the button is styled a different shade of blue and has black text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX9XI.png)

[The primary style is showing correctly as seen here when I change my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqPQU.png)

I checked the DOM and the css also shows the color to appear this way.
[Screenshot from the inspect developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB57Z.png)

Thank you for reading and I would really appreciate it if you could help. P.S. How do I make it so that my pictures appear instead of links to click. I pasted them in so if there is another way please advise. Again, thank you.

I checked over my code and made sure nothing was overriding the styles. There is nothing that I noticed. It is a very small project.

I also tested the other default button styles, and they appeared as shown on the bootstrap documentation page.

I tested my code in the Chrome Browser and it also is appearing this way.

Comment: I checked this form to see if anyone had anything similar to me happen to them and I found this person. Their issue is almost identical, and a solution was not found. They posted their question over a year ago.

Here is a link to their [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68309404/bootstrap-styling-working-but-not-the-same-looking-anymore)

[Screenshot of their post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhz9S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"...but I just want to understand why it is happening."*

By default, Bootstrap uses a utility mixin ([button-variant()](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#mixins)) which decides whether the button's text color should be light or dark, based on the button's main (background) color.

This mixin calculates all color variants for the button (focus, active, disabled, hovered). The mixin is overridable (and some bootstrap themes do have their own bespoke version of it).

The exact function determining the text color is called `color-contrast()` and takes the background color as parameter.

This is in line with WCAG's directives for minimum contrast (1.4.3 and 2.1). Documented [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/accessibility/#color-contrast).
Please take note of the following recommendation from Bootstrap:

> *Authors are encouraged to test their specific uses of color and, where necessary, manually modify/extend these default colors to ensure adequate color contrast ratios.*

Comment: Thank you so much! I am learning web development so this was my first time using bootstrap. I just wanted to be sure it wasn't an issue I was causing on my end. Thank you much for this information.

Comment: @FeatherPiano, it's peculiar you marked a wrong answer as accepted. The text color is changed by Bootstrap's internal `color-contrast()` utility, which is not a third-party extension. As a general rule, [SO] answers are accepted based on facts, rather than beliefs.

Comment: Thank you tao, I changed the accepted answer to yours. I forget that just because someone responds doesn't mean their responses hold truth. And here I was about to head down another rabbit hole due to this so I really really appreciate your correction. This makes a lot more sense now. ^^

Answer (score -1):

I believe the culprit is some sort of third party extension. If you go to bootstrap [buttons page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/)  what you actually should see is:
[image]
You can try using an incognito window or a clean browser to verify this, but I believe that some sort of extension is distorting your view. For example, I use "Dark Reader" and in my case buttons have this appearance:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for answering. Wow I did not know so much factors went into determining the colors. That is very interesting, again thank you!

Comment: I don´t believe its factored in by bootstrap, rather just an effect of third party applications on a given css